# Subtract hours and minutes from a time entered in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, time, excel-2010, excel-2013

I want to know the time when **12 hrs and 30 mins** is subtracted from a time let us say **10:00 AM**(it should display **9:30 PM**). But since excel by default stores this date as 1st Jan 1990, I am getting a negative timing and excel does not display it. How do I make sure that when a time is entered in a cell,I can subtract certain hours from it and display the time in AM/PM format? PS: I tried changing it to 1904 format,but this did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's enough to put

```
=MOD(A2-B2,1)
```

where the first time is in A2 and the second in B2.

That will get the fraction part (the hours) and give it a positive sign which should be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Tom. That was simple and helpful.